# Not understading close and end events in sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets

I don't understand `close` and `end` event.

```
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end();
});

server.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("close", () => {
        console.log("closed");
    })
    socket.on("end", () => {
        console.log("ended");
    })
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Only thing I know is the `close` event is trigerred after ca. 5 seconds.

Comment: In this context, 'close' and 'end' are listening for events emitted by the socket instance. Look up Node event emitters for more info (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `close` and `end` events for a socket are described here: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end and https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1.

In a nutshell, the `end` is event is half closed and the `close` event is fully closed.  You can read the above links for more detail on what half closed means.

Usually, one wants to listen to the `close` event (fully closed) unless you are doing lower level networking things.

For an http request socket (which is what your example shows), these represent the end of the life of the http request connection.  The normal cycle is the client connects to your http server, that creates a socket connection between client and server, the request data is received, server sends response data, socket is closed.  The server remains active, listening for more incoming connections.

http request sockets can be closed because a response was sent and the transmission is done (the whole http request/response cycle is done), because an error occurred or because they eventually timed out with no response.